# Convert OpenCV mat to Android Bitmap

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap

I am trying to convert an OpenCV mat to android Bitmap but that gives me images with a bluish tint(yellow colour turns to blue)! Even though I am not doing any processing on the image! I have no clue why this is happening. Below is some relevant code:

```
File file = new File(imgDecodableString);
image = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getAbsolutePath(),Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.cols(),  image.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
Utils.matToBitmap(image, resultBitmap);
Bitmap mResult = resultBitmap;
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
imgView.setImageBitmap(mResult);
//imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
```

I am new to android app development so I might be missing something simple. Thanks for help!

EDIT:

I am uploading images for reference.

[image: Original image]

[image: Image I am getting]

Comment: Can you upload the two images as well, I suspect there is some RGB2BGR issue, but viewing your source code it seems to be less probable.

Comment: @ZdaR I have uploaded the images. Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected, the issue is with the `RGB` color convention, Android follows `RGB` color convention, but OpenCV follows `BGR` color convention, You can rectify it using `Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)`, before displaying it in the `ImageView`.

Comment: You mean like this:
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);

Because it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Based on the given suggestions, I made a function which converts Mat to Bitmap. This function works perfectly.!

```
private static Bitmap convertMatToBitMap(Mat input){
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    Mat rgb = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(input, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

    try {
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb.cols(), rgb.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(rgb, bmp);
    }
    catch (CvException e){
        Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    return bmp;
}
```